# Android TextView setting text and color

Tags: java, android

I would like to set the size and color of the text at random during onCreate method

Here is my code:

```
private TextView start;
private boolean isClicked;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    start = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStart);

    isclick = false;
    Random r = new Random();

    while (isclick = false)
    {

        start.setTextSize(r.nextInt(50));
        start.setTextColor(Color.rgb(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                r.nextInt(256)));
    }


}
```

This code of mine doesn't work.

During onCreate I want the text size and color continuously and randomly changing.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Does it not start at all? Does it only change color once? Does it not change color at all?

Comment: it doesnt change color and text size at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me :( let me know is there is a problem )

```
private boolean isclick;
Handler handler ; 
private TextView start;
private boolean isClicked;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        start = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStart);
        handler = new Handler();

        isclick = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                 while (isclick == false)
                    {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Random r = new Random();



                            start.setTextSize(r.nextInt(50));
                            start.setTextColor(Color.rgb(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256),
                                    r.nextInt(256)));

                        }

                    });
                     Log.w("DEBUG","Text View  value : "+ start.getText().toString());

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }


            }
        }).start();



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a handler sins your are modifying UI widgets 
[this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) article may help you .

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that works on a TextView called x

```
//create random value between 0 and 70
int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*70);
x.setTextSize((float)random);

int red = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*255);
int green = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*255);
int blue = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*255);

Color randomcolor = new Color();

if (red < 16){
    hexred = "0" + Integer.toHexString(red);
}else {
    hexred = Integer.toHexString(red);
}
if (green < 16){
    hexgreen = "0" + Integer.toHexString(green);
}else {
    hexgreen = Integer.toHexString(green);
}
if (blue < 16){
    hexblue = "0" + Integer.toHexString(blue);
}else {
    hexblue = Integer.toHexString(blue);
}

String color = "#" + hexred + hexgreen + hexblue;

x.setTextColor(randomcolor.parseColor(color));
```

Continuasly changing is not recommended however. If you want to make it continuasly change color, chance is that the update of the color and size are to slow that nothing is displayed. Also it might happen that the entire XML layout is not loaded because of the calculations on the xml.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your text randomly changing continously, use thread.
put your "while" action. inside run method, and give some delay on it.

Comment: Not a good idea to access a UI widget from a thread directly... use `runOnUiThread` to do this safely.

Comment: there's Handlers that can be used also :)

Comment: yes. thats true. thanks for the correction. using thread in android is bad way. ronOnUiThread and handlres is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of a missing = in the `isclick = false` if clause. It should be `isclick==false`.